# SQL , работа с AGAINST, полнотекстовый поиск

Tags: sql

У меня есть данный SQL код. 
Я хочу, чтобы мне вернуло ВСЕ данные , где data_index 
включает в себя `wd5000aaks V0 TJ 2010`, и чтобы оно искало по отдельности, а не как строка. 
Тоесть отдельно `wd5000aaks`AND `V0` AND `TJ` AND `2010`

Но данный поиск работает только если остается `wd5000aaks`, в других случаях оно возвращает пустоту, но данные с информацией для данного поиска - есть

У меня есть такое описание

```
hdd with serial number: wcawf3605242model: wd5000aaks-75v0a0date: 04 mar 2010dcm: harchtjabnproduct of: thailandpcb sticker: 2061-701640-k02 05pd5pcb revision: 2060-701640-002 rev a
```

И я когда делаю поиск по V0, то `WD5000AAKS-75V0A0` внутри него есть V0, но оно его не видит, и не вернет. А если введу WD500 - найдет. 
То есть проблема в том, что оно не ищет по СЕРЕДИНЕ как %LIKE%
Как сделать так, чтобы оно искало неважно где находится слово.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, SUM(score) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT 
DISTINCT  `eav_index`.`entity_id`, (((0)) * 1 + LEAST((MATCH (data_index) 
AGAINST ('+wd5000aaks* +V0 +TJ +2010*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)), 1000000) * POW(2, 
search_weight)) AS `score` FROM `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `eav_index`
INNER JOIN `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1` AS `search_index` ON 
eav_index.entity_id = search_index.entity_id
INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `cea` ON search_index.attribute_id = 
cea.attribute_id
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_index` ON 
stock_index.product_id = eav_index.entity_id AND `stock_index`.`website_id` 
= 0 AND `stock_index`.`stock_status` = 1 AND `stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1 
WHERE (eav_index.store_id = '1') AND (`eav_index`.`attribute_id` = 99 AND 
`eav_index`.`value` in ('3', '4') AND `eav_index`.`store_id` = '1') AND 
(MATCH (data_index) AGAINST ('+wd5000aaks* +V0 +TJ +2010*' IN BOOLEAN 
 MODE))) AS `main_select` GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC, 
 `entity_id` DESC
 LIMIT 10000
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего срабатывает игнорирование токенов размером менее заданного минимума (скажем, не индексируются слова короче 3 символов). Перестройте индекс.

Comment: Это стоит сделать в таблице или где? Я использую фреймворк magento2, и от него я получил данный SQL

Comment: Я думаю, что для начала Вам нужно почитать документацию на Вашу СУБД (MySQL?) в части, касающейся полнотекстового поиска, вообще, и его настройки в частности.

Comment: Я немного изменил вопрос, не могли бы вы посмотреть?

Comment: Вы вообще ищете подстроку. По крайней мере для токенов `V0`, `TJ`. Полнотекст в этом случае неприменим. Используйте комбинацию из нескольких LOCATE().

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное за помощь!